# Find an algorithm that minimize the maximum distance of two sets, better than Greedy algorithm

Tags: algorithm, matlab, optimization, matrix, functional-programming

Here is the interesting but complicated problem:

Suppose we have two sets of points. One set A includes points in some space grid, like regular 1D or 3D grid. The other set B includes points that are randomly spaced and are of the same size as the space grid. Mathematically, we could order the two sets and construct a corresponding matrix with respect to the distance between A and B. For example, A(i, j) may refer to the distance between i of A and j of B.

Given some ordering, we have a matrix. Then, the diagonal element (i,i) in the matrix is the distance between point i of A and point i of B. The problem is how to find a good reordering/indexing such that the maximum distance is as small as possible? In matrix form, how to find a good reordering/indexing such that the largest diagonal element as small as possible?

Notes from myself:

1. Suppose set A is corresponding to rows of the matrix, and set B is to columns of the matrix. Then reordering the matrix means we are doing row/column permutation. Therefore, our problem is equivalent to find a good permutation to minimize the largest diagonal element.
2. Greedy algorithm may be a choice. But I am trying to find an ideally perfect reordering that minimize the largest diagonal element.

Comment: have you taken a look at this? http://mathoverflow.net/questions/24215/optimization-over-permutation

Comment: I don't understand the problem.  What are the off-diagonal elements of the ordering matrix?  What do you mean by "we could order the two sets and construct a corresponding matrix"?

Comment: @user2654818 Thank you for your time. Let me reword that part: we could order the two sets and construct a corresponding matrix with respect to the distance between A and B. For example, A(i, j) may refer to the distance between i of A and j of B.

Comment: @prgao I didnt take a look at that question until I saw your message. Thanks a lot. That is pretty helpful.

Comment: @prgao So my problem is an assignment problem? Given an reordering $\Pi$ of A, for each point in A, I have got its own minimum distance to the set of B. So my cost function would be the maximum distance among all the points of A. And the optimization problem is trying to minimize the maximum distance, i.e., f. It's like $\min_{\Pi} \max_{x\in A}\{d(x, y), y\in B\}$.

Comment: Did you figure out the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reordering you are referring to is essentially a correspondence problem i.e. you are trying to find the closest match for each point in the other set. The greedy algorithm will work fine. The distance you are looking for is commonly referred to as the [Hausdorff distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance).

Comment: Thanks man. The Hausdorff dis you mentioned is full of inspiration. Other than greedy algorithm, do you know any better algorithm?

Comment: My problem is a bit easier. I want to find one side minimum: $\min_{\Pi} \max_{x\in A}\{d(x, y), y\in B\}$.

Comment: And in terms of your question: if your input set is much smaller than your query set then a good method is to build a kd-tree using your input set and the  query the closest point to every point in the query set by using the kdtree.

Comment: thanks a lot. I am looking at kd-tree wiki now. I am major in math so I am not very familiar with algorithm. You are really smart!!! Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. Good luck with your studies! On SO when an answer fits the question you need to mark it as the official answer so the responder can be recognized for his\her efforts. If this is the case here please mark the answer in the tick box.

Comment: Please elaborate on what kind of greedy algorithm would work. Also the definition of hausdorff distance is a lot looser. It's totally possible that there's N to 1 mapping while calculating it. I think we are looking for 1 to 1 mapping here. Once the point is mapped, it can't be mapped again.